# Orientdb has very slow performance when inserting with duplicate checking

Tags: java, nosql, orientdb

I am using the REST API to send a batch of SQL commands to OrientDB.  Each batch contains about 6000 vertices and 13200 edges.  I am creating vertices and edges using a csv, 1 batch is all the queries generated from parsing 100 rows in the csv.  I am checking for duplicates before inserting either, as follows:

Vertex

```
UPDATE vertex SET property1 = "property1", property2 = "property2" UPSERT WHERE property1 = "property1";
```

Edge (using this method since UPSERT not supported with edges)

```
LET $1 = SELECT expand(bothE("edge1")) FROM vertex1 WHERE property1 = "property1";
LET $2 = SELECT expand(bothE("edge1")) FROM vertex2 WHERE property1 = "property1";
LET $3 = SELECT INTERSECT($1, $2);
IF($3.INTERSECT.size() == 0) {
LET $4 = CREATE EDGE edge1 FROM (SELECT FROM vertex1 WHERE property1 = "property1") TO (SELECT FROM vertex2 WHERE property1 = "property1");
```

The 1st batch takes about 50 seconds, then the second takes about 250 seconds, and the third over 1000 seconds.  I suspect that searching previous records for duplicates is what is slowing it down, however its such a small amount of data I suspect that either my duplicate checking or the server config is to blame.

Is there a better way to check for duplicates?  I've updated my server config to use the following:

```
storage.diskCache.bufferSize = 40GB
query.parallelMinimumRecords = 1
storage.useWAL = false
```

Any advice appreciated

Comment: Did you create a unique index on `vertex`.`property1` ?

Comment: Hi, what version are you using? Thx

Comment: @wolf4ood I tried that first, but it prevents duplicates being inserted, which is good, but also raises an error, which is bad.  I would need to handle that error server side as I need to cut down on back and forth between server and client as much as possible.

Comment: @MichelaBonizzi I'm using 2.2.25